# Removing Firebase Realtime Database node using Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I can successfully get a query param and post it into my realtime database at a path defined by the query param itself, using this code:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.emptyHat = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  // Grab the group parameter.
  const group = req.query.group;
  // Push the new message into the Realtime Database using the Firebase Admin SDK.
  const snapshot = await admin.database().ref('/group').push({list: group});
  // Redirect with 303 SEE OTHER to the URL of the pushed object in the Firebase console.
  res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref.toString());
});
```

If the query param was 'test', the result would be a new entry at **/test/{firebaseID}/{'list':'test'}**

When I tried to modify it to remove the node named in the query parameter I get errors.
(I'm trying to remove that top level **/test** node

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();


exports.emptyHat = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  // Grab the group parameter.
  const group = req.query.group;
  // Remove the node at the location 'group'.
  functions.database().ref('/group').remove();
  // Redirect with 303 SEE OTHER to the URL of the pushed object in the Firebase console.
  //res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref.toString());
});
```

Error message in the logs:

```
    at exports.emptyHat.functions.https.onRequest (/srv/index.js:95:13)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:49:9)
    at /worker/worker.js:783:7
    at /worker/worker.js:766:11
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second function is ignoring the promise returned by the Firebase API.  This makes it unlikely to work in Cloud Functions.  Cloud Functions HTTP triggers require that you only send a response only after all the asynchronous work is complete.  After your function generates a response, it will terminate and clean up any async work still in progress.  That work might not complete.

Your second function should be more like your first one, and use the promise returned by [remove()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#remove) and wait for it to complete before sending the response:

```
exports.emptyHat = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const group = req.query.group;
  await admin.database().ref('/group').remove();
  // send the response here.
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I've updated to 

```exports.emptyHat = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const group = req.query.group;
  const snapshot = await functions.database().ref('/group').remove();
  // send the response here.
  res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref.toString());
});```

but still getting this error:

Comment: error:
```TypeError: functions.database is not a function
    at exports.emptyHat.functions.https.onRequest (/srv/index.js:102:36)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:49:9)
    at /worker/worker.js:783:7
    at /worker/worker.js:766:11
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)```

Comment: Actually, your code was also incorrect trying to use `functions` to delete anything.  You need to use `admin`.

Comment: that seems to have helped a bit with the errors...! still not working though, getting this in the logs:
```TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined
    at exports.emptyHat.functions.https.onRequest (/srv/index.js:104:30)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)```